# Is there a way to combine java persistence sequence @annotations into one annotation?

Tags: java, jpa

I often use the following combination of annotations to reference a SQL sequence existing in the DB (and not managed in Java).

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "my_seq")
```

I'd like to simplify this to a single `@SequencedBy("my_seq")`.

More generally, if I've got two annotations

```
@A(param1 = "paramVal", param2 = "paramVal")
@B(param = "paramVal")
```

and I always use them together with the same arguments as seen above, is there a way to simplify it to a single annotation? e.g. `@C(param = "paramVal")`?

Comment: No. A JPA provider looks for THOSE annotations. You introduce one of your own to provide the same info and you're screwed